# How is it possible that ops traits are not in scope?

Tags: rust

I personally dislike the lack of readability of `!` operator, so I prefer to use `.not()`.

While (obviously) one can write something like this:

```
fn main() {
    let some_condition = false;

    if !some_condition {
        println!("condition is false");
    }
}
```

This does not work with `some_condition.not()` unless I import `std::ops::Not`. Why is it so? I thought that one can use operators in Rust because their trait are in scope. `!` is a shortcut to call the `not` method, is not it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. The compiler translates the operators to calls to the trait functions (except for primitives, where it translates them directly to low-level operations <sup>1</sup>), but the traits need not be in scope for that.

Or, if you will, you can think of it that the compiler translates the operators to fully-qualified calls, i.e. `!some_condition` becomes `::std::ops::Not::not(some_condition)`, which obviously doesn't care about whether any use directives are in scope or not.

---

**1.** [Here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.23.0/src/libcore/ops/arith.rs#L89-L102) is where `Add` is implemented for the primitive types. Note that the definition of `add` for those is `self + other`! Clearly, this impl isn't ever actually used by the compiler.

Comment: Do you have a reference for "translates them directly to low-level operations"? You could say it's obvious, as the trait implementations for the primitive types use the operators, and it would loop otherwise...)

Comment: @Stefan [Here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/arith.rs.html#92-98) is where Add is implemented for the primitive types. Note that the *definition* of `add` for those is `self + other`! Clearly, this `impl` isn't ever actually used by the compiler.