# Difference between add and +?

Tags: rust, addition, traits

I am reading [Rust by Examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/ops.html).

The code below works.

```rust
println!("Bar + Foo = {:?}", Bar + Foo);
```

but, below not works though both struct and trait implementation are in scope.

```rust
println!("Bar + Foo = {:?}", Bar.add(Foo));
```

Full code:

```rust
use std::ops;

struct Foo;
struct Bar;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct FooBar;

impl ops::Add<Bar> for Foo {
    type Output = FooBar;

    fn add(self, _rhs: Bar) -> FooBar {
        println!("> Foo.add(Bar) was called");

        FooBar
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Foo + Bar = {:?}", Foo + Bar);
    println!("Foo + Bar = {:?}", Foo.add(Bar));
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `add` found for type `Foo` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:21:38
   |
3  | struct Foo;
   | ----------- method `add` not found for this
...
21 |     println!("Foo + Bar = {:?}", Foo.add(Bar));
   |                                      ^^^
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope, perhaps add a `use` for it:
   |
1  | use std::ops::Add;
   |
```

Why not?

Comment: I guess you haven't import `Add` by adding `use std::ops::Add;` to the file(trait must be visible in the file) : [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=113eeb1c952bc45ec5dafa5b8c6eb28e)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP needs to read error messages.

Comment: @jhpratt error message might be confusing for the newcomer to Rust, OP thinks it should work because implementation is already in scope and error message says (items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope)

Comment: @ÖmerErden Sometimes the error message aren't clear — that's absolutely not the case here. The compiler says what the error is _and how to fix it_ in actual code.

Comment: @jhpratt sure, maybe the question should have been asked in this way: _i have implementation in scope but compiler tells me "you don't have it in scope" why ?_.

Comment: The "why" is literally "you don't have this line that we are literally giving you"

Comment: @ jhpratt Thank you for clear my question. Then would you tell me i have implementation in scope but compiler tells me "you don't have it in scope" why? and What is difference between "+" operator and "add" operator as one works but the other not.

Comment: The underlying question is a duplicate of [How is it possible that ops traits are not in scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48803064/3650362)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the compiler said:

> items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope

just do what the compiler advice you:

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

fn main() {
    println!("Foo + Bar = {:?}", Foo + Bar);
    println!("Foo + Bar = {:?}", Foo.add(Bar));
}
```

To be clear :

"*below not works though both struct and trait implementation are in scope*"

This is not correct, the trait `Add` is not in the scope, you only have `ops` module, this is totally different than `use std::ops::Add;`. You can also see that in your implementation, you write `ops::Add<Bar>` not `Add<Bar>` so `Add` is not in the scope in your code just `ops`.

> If items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope, then how "Foo + Bar" works? What is difference between "+" and "add"?

`+` is just a syntax sugar, a magic thing that compiler do for you. How it works doesn't really matter, `+` doesn't need anything to call `add()` (because it's a builtin, the compiler "know" what to do) but if you call it yourself, compiler has no reason to not apply general rules about trait and also rules about import this trait in the scope (some trait are import by default but not `Add`). `+` is special but not `Add` trait. The same apply to `?` operator and many more in rust. We use trait to implement some basic operator, this is really clean and very flexible.

Comment: Would you give me some more information? (1) How Foo is used here without instantiation? (2) Foo clearly implemented Add<Bar>, then why Foo can't call the trait method "add"? That is to say, Foo.add(). Is that related to "items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope"?

Comment: If items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope, then how "Foo + Bar" works? What is difference between "+" and "add"? Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: Would you explain me why "+" works and "add" not? I think, in the same circumstance, both work or both don't.

Comment: @주피터 you shouldn't consider `Foo.add(Bar)` same with `Foo + Bar`,`Foo + Bar` is exactly same with `std::ops::Add::add(Foo, Bar)`. please read [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/call-expr.html#disambiguating-function-calls)

Comment: @Ömer Erden Exactly what I want. Thanks Erden.